# cookiejar.Newが返すエラー値が必ずnilなのは何故か

Tags: go

[net/http/cookiejar](https://golang.org/src/net/http/cookiejar/jar.go#L75) に一見不思議そうなコードがありました。
戻り値の型宣言では `error` を指定しているにも関わらず、関数内にはエラーを扱う箇所がなく必ず `nil` を返しています。

```
func New(o *Options) (*Jar, error) {
    jar := &Jar{
        entries: make(map[string]map[string]entry),
    }
    if o != nil {
        jar.psList = o.PublicSuffixList
    }
    return jar, nil
}
```

本来であれば戻り値がひとつだけ（`*Jar` を返すだけ）で十分のように思えますが、Go言語的には何か意味のある書き方なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

未だにこの形で残っている主たる理由は、Go 1内での互換性のようです。

GoのGitHub上で[この件についてのIssue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18685)が2017年1月に立っていました。これによると、

- 元々、何かしらの理由で戻り値にerrorが入れられる (将来的にerrorを返すことを見越したAPI設計かと予想されていますが確認されていません)。
- その後そのまま放置され、今に至る。今更APIを変更すると互換性を失うので、そのままにしておく。

という経緯のようです。

元々cookiejarの今の形のデザインが議論されたのが[このメール](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/ygDB3nbir00/discussion)みたいですが特に説明はなく、ファイルの変化を追いつつソースのコミットやそのコードレビューを見ても特に説明になるようなコメントが残されていないので(※)、本当の所はAPI設計者に聞いてみるしか無さそうです。

- 参考

  - ["net/http/cookiejar: New does not need an error as return argument"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18685) -- GitHub - golang/go
  - ["Go 1.1 cookiejar"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/ygDB3nbir00/discussion) -- golang-dev

※ exp/cookiejarとして[最初に出来たとき](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/478aff3d4d7eea7f9980f960957eb21ae77aa2c2/src/pkg/exp/cookiejar/jar.go#L62)には戻り値にerrorが含まれておらず、その後上述のメールの通り[errorが含まれる形に変更](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/7d8cc587b2f459d773d71ec2e220173de6e60f86/src/pkg/exp/cookiejar/jar.go#L56)。この時にはまだ実装がありませんが、[その次のコミット](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/8c6489bc27b639487f56392d13c43f95fab0ac20/src/pkg/exp/cookiejar/jar.go#L67)で今の実装と同じものになっています。コードレビューの内容はコミットメッセージにリンクが貼られています。